# Security issue with controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have my Banks Controller

```
class Api::V1::BanksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json

  # PUT /api/v1/banks/:id.json
  def update
    @bank = UserBank.find_by!(uuid: params[:id])

    if @bank.update_attributes bank_params
      render json: @bank
    else
      render json: @bank.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def bank_params
     params.require(:bank).permit(:iban, :bic)
  end
end
```

I'm using devise for the authentication. My problem comes from the fact that any users can update another user's bank object just by getting the access-token from the login response.

Is there a clean/secure/automatic way of preventing a user to interact with somebody else's details ? 
or should I just make sure that the bank object I'm updating belongs to the logged-in user ?

thanks a lot

Comment: If you have relationship for user and user_bank then you can use current_user.user_banks.find()

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing up authentication and authorization.

[*Authentication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) is concerned with the identity of the user.

[*Authorization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) is a set of rules for who is allowed to do what in your application.

Devise provides *authentication*, you can either create your own *authorization* system or use a library (recommended) such as [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

A hacky home rolled authorization check would look like:

```
class AuthorizationError < StandardError; end

class ApplicationController
  rescue_from AuthorizationError, with: :deny_access

  def deny_access
    head :unauthorized and return
  end
end

class Api::V1::BanksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_bank!
  before_action :authorize!
  respond_to :json

  # PUT /api/v1/banks/:id.json
  def update
    @bank = UserBank.find_by!(uuid: params[:id])
    respond_with @bank.update(bank_params)
  end

  private
  def set_bank!
    @bank = UserBank.find_by!(uuid: params[:id])
  end

  def authorize!
    # this is the authorization rule.
    unless @bank.user == current_user
      raise AuthorizationError 
    end
  end

  def bank_params
     params.require(:bank).permit(:iban, :bic)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you didn't know this you should stay far away from programming anything banking related. Just sayin'